# iOS Cocoapods copy widgetExtension resource into main assets.car

Tags: ios, cocoapods

my widgetExtension xcassets only add target to widgetExtension not main app. But pod copys these images into main-app's assets.car. So these images exist in both the assets of the main app and the assets of the extension.

I think it’s mainly because of this automatically generated code in the pod script.

```
if [[ -n "${WRAPPER_EXTENSION}" ]] && [ "`xcrun --find actool`" ] && [ -n "${XCASSET_FILES:-}" ]
then
  # Find all other xcassets (this unfortunately includes those of path pods and other targets).
  OTHER_XCASSETS=$(find -L "$PWD" -iname "*.xcassets" -type d)
  while read line; do
    if [[ $line != "${PODS_ROOT}*" ]]; then
      XCASSET_FILES+=("$line")
    fi
  done <<<"$OTHER_XCASSETS"

  if [ -z ${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME+x} ]; then
    printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform "${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target "${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --compress-pngs --compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
  else
    printf "%s\0" "${XCASSET_FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 xcrun actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --platform "${PLATFORM_NAME}" --minimum-deployment-target "${!DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME}" ${TARGET_DEVICE_ARGS} --compress-pngs --compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info_cocoapods.plist"
  fi
fi
```